# Delphi - Склеить 2 png

Tags: delphi, изображения, png, delphi-xe3

Как на `delphi` склеить 2 `png`.
Одну картинку поставить рядом с другой.
Картинки горизонтальные, вот такие:

[image: img]

Delphi XE3

Процедура склеивает 2 png, проверил, на диск сохраняет нормально склеенную картинку в самой процедуре, но за пределами процедуры уже проблема:

```
procedure CombinePics(png1, png2, png1_res: TPngImage);
var
  b1, b2, b3: TBitmap;
begin
  b1 :=TBitmap.Create;
  b2 :=TBitmap.Create;
  b3 :=TBitmap.Create;
  b1.Assign(png1);
  b2.Assign(png2);
  b3.Width := b1.Width + b2.Width;
  if b1.Height > b2.Height then
    b3.Height := b1.Height
  else
    b3.Height := b2.Height;
  b3.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, b1);
  b3.Canvas.Draw(b1.Width, 0, b2);
//  b3.SaveToFile('d:\b3.bmp');
  png1_res := TPngImage.Create;
  png1_res.Assign(b3);
  png1_res.SaveToFile('d:\11.png');//здесь сохраняется картинка нормально на диск, видно ,что картинки склеены корректно
  b1.Free;
  b2.Free;
  b3.Free;
end;
```

Вот так использую:

```
Var
  png1, png2, png_res: TPngImage;
begin
...
...
...
      png1 := TPngImage.Create;
      png2 := TPngImage.Create;
      png_res := TPngImage.Create;
//загружаю картинки из MemoryStream
      png1.LoadFromStream(Arr[0].img);
      png2.LoadFromStream(Arr[1].img);
      CombinePics(png1, png2, png_res);//склеиваю
      png_res.SaveToFile('d:\_merge1.png');// сохраняется пустой файл
```

Но сохраняется пустой файл.

Answer (score 1):

Вот эта строчка: `png1_res := TPngImage.Create;` в коде метода `CombinePics` лишняя.

Переменная `png1_res` уже содержит объект класса `TPngImage` (вы его создали до вызова). Этой строчкой вы создаете новый объект и утечку памяти. Этот объект никто никогда не освободит потому, что за пределами метода `CombinePics` о нем никто не знает. Если вы сделаете параметр `png1_res` переменой (`procedure CombinePics(png1, png2: TPngImage; var png1_res: TPngImage);`), то создание объекта внутри метода можно оставить, но в таком случае его не нужно создавать до вызова метода, иначе будет утечка того объекта, который вы создали до вызова.

---

**UPD:**
Этот вариант `CombinePics` будет короче и быстрее:

```
procedure CombinePics(png1, png2, png1_res: TPngImage);
begin
  if png1.Height > png2.Height then
    png1_res.SetSize(png1.Width + png2.Width, png1.Height)
  else
    png1_res.SetSize(png1.Width + png2.Width, png2.Height);
  png1_res.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, png1);
  png1_res.Canvas.Draw(png1.Width, 0, png2);
//  png1_res.SaveToFile('d:\11.png'); //здесь сохраняется картинка нормально на диск, видно, что картинки склеены корректно
 end;
```

---

**UPD2:** Опять я повелся на вопрос двухлетней давности :(

Answer (score 0):

Создать промежуточный TImage или любой др. граф. объект, и в его canvas, с помощью методов Draw и StretchDraw, вывести изображения в рассчитанных X и Y координатах.